# Is the phrase "It's not going to be." grammatically correct in English?

Tags: phrase-meaning

Is the phrase "It's not going to be." grammatically correct in English? Please, note the period in the end of the phrase. In other words, I don't mean such cases like "Looks like it's not going to be **easy**." or "Looks like it's not going to be **soon enough**.", etc.

Also, if the phrase is common and grammatically correct, does it convey any meaning different from "Looks like it's not going to **happen**."?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for grammar, ***It's not going to be.*** is grammatically correct. For *to be* is synonymous of *to exist, live* (in certain cases), I doubt that the above mentioned phrase could be used on its own; that should definitely be extended.

> *You mean the party? It's going to be **at nine o'clock**.* (This sentence would make sense to me.)

As for its commonness, I, for one, don't think that ***It's not going to be.*** will mean the same as ***It's not going to happen.*** in a conversation. Check the following video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TofLNxbC4v0

I don't think that the one with *be* would be so commonly used.